# Unable to rotate cube in desired manner - plane and mousemove method

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

The cube should stay flat but rotate towards the cursor, with only one type of rotation (2d - top-down). My concern now is that it may be due to centring the mesh against itself? Please help!

View here:
https://thecoop.group/conquest/ground

The code begins here:
https://github.com/the-coop/coopwebsite/blob/89ca8909ed3fe28afd79b34c5305b63aabba8638/lib/conquest/ground/engine/setupGroundMovement.js#L35

Here is the excerpt, I have tried many different ways and some of the experimental code may remain:

```
    const plane = new Plane(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 1);
    const raycaster = new Raycaster();
    const mouse = new Vector2();
    const pointOfIntersection = new Vector3();


    document.addEventListener('mousemove', ev => {
        const { camera, me } = window.GROUND_LEVEL;

        mouse.x = ( ev.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( ev.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
        raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
        
        if (me.mesh) {
            // Attempt to make mesh "look at" (rotate) to target position.
            me.mesh.geometry.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`pointOfIntersection` has 3 dimensions that correspond to the cube's three axes.

If you only want the cube to rotate on one axis, try specifying `0` for the other axes in [`Object3D#lookAt`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt).

```js
// The cube will rotate on its Y axis when following a point on the X axis
me.mesh.geometry.lookAt(pointOfIntersection.x, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right though, how can something rotate to the point of a cursor (x, y) by passing only the x?

Comment: THE CAMERA IS .add()ed to the cube!!!!!! And the raycaster is from the camera?!?!?!!?